# What is the Use of Repeat.Any() in Expect.Call while using Rhino Mocks Test framework

Tags: rhino-mocks

When I use Repeat.Any() it doesn't show any error though I don't call GetMood() Method ,but if i don't use n doesn't call GetMood then it shows Excpetion of type ExpectationViolationException.Can somebody tell me what is the use of repeat.any().

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();

IAnimal animal = mocks.DynamicMock<IAnimal>();

using (mocks.Record())  
{                 
    //Expect.Call(animal.GetMood()).Return("punit");   
    Expect.Call(animal.GetMood()).Return("Punit").Repeat.Any();
}

//animal.GetMood();

mocks.ReplayAll();   
mocks.VerifyAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeat.Any specifies that GetMood() can be called 0 or more times and that it should return "Punit" if it is called.

The line

```
Expect.Call(animal.GetMood()).Return("punit");
```

implies that GetMood must be called exactly once.  This is the same as Repat.Once.

You may also use AtLeastOnce, Times, Twice, and Never.

Comment: thnx for reply actually if u see my questions which states that if i use repeat.any and odn't call the method it deosn't show any expectation,but if i don't use repeat.any it throws exception.is repeat.any autmatically calls the method.

Comment: Repeat.Any means that you don't care how many times your method is being called so it will not throw an exception even if your method is not called at all.